# What causes this error during our DevOps build

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

We have a Visual Studio project in Azure Devops. We are using VS2019.

The build was working with this project. However, earlier this week the build stopped working. The error message is below.

I checked the build server. The .Net framework 4 is installed. Also, the project framework has not changed.

It looks like the MSBUILD is trying to use VS2022.

How can I change the build to use the VS2019 MSBUILD? How is this set?

How can I correct the below error?

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): 

Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found
```

Comment: We had a similar error which was cured by changing the pools vmImage as suggested by @KJN:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.`

Answer (score 17):

Think I figured it out myself. In your yaml file, change the target vmImage from windows-latest, to windows-2019.

```
pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be caused by environment variables of Azure Agent server(build serer).

You can review environment variables via

project setting - agent pools - your agent pool - agents tab - agent - capabilities tab

[image]

check value of MSBuild variable, to see if it point to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin"

if so, login Azure Agent server then update MSBuild variable to VS2019.